# Login screen push up while typing on android and iphone

Tags: android, ios, react-native, keyboard

```
import { TextField } from 'react-native-material-textfield';    

  <KeyboardAvoidingView
     behavior={'position'}
     style={styles.container}
    >
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TextField label='username' value={username}/>
        <TextField label='password' value={password}/>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text> Login </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text> Register </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

I want to push the login screen screen up while typing on android and iphone using software keyboard.

I have tried it using **KeyboardAvoidingView** component but its not working for me.

When i am using behavior={'position'} when keyboard comes it is goes out of the screen.

Please suggest me any solution if anyone know.

[image]

Comment: why don't you use [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html)?

Comment: I tried using **KeyboardAvoidingView** but its not working

Comment: Why not? How did you set it up?

Comment: @ishita-sinha i have edited the question now please tell me how can i use the attributes of this component

Comment: this component work but there is an issue to control position when keyboard comes

Comment: try `keyboardVerticalOffset` to control that position. And you can also try with the different values of `behavior`.

Comment: try IQKeyboardManager for iOS

Comment: I have used KeyboardAvoidingView but i am unable to control the position as screen goes to topmost. i also tried using 'keyboardVerticalOffset'  but it is not working for me.  I have also added the image which i am facing issue. Please suggest me any solution to control the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code from KeyboardAwareScrollView

```
  resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
   scrollEnabled={false}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used **keyboardVerticalOffset={-30}** in KeyboardAvoidingView component and now its working.

```
import { TextField } from 'react-native-material-textfield';    
 <KeyboardAvoidingView
  keyboardVerticalOffset={-30}
  behavior={'position'}
  style={styles.container}
 >
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <TextField label='username' value={username}/>
    <TextField label='password' value={password}/>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text> Login </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text> Register </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```